# Bootstrap error: The selector ".alert-success" was not found

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have not made any changes, I believe, and bootstrap is now throwing an error on every page stating:

```
.alert-notice" failed to @extend ".alert-success".
The selector ".alert-success" was not found.
Use "@extend .alert-success !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
```

I've searched and searched, and can not figure out what the issue is.
Any thoughts here?

application.scss

```
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";

header {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    font-color: white;
}

body    {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}



.wrapper    {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.clear  {
    clear: both;
}

.profile-container  {
    clear: both;
}

.alert-notice {
  @extend .alert-success;
}

.alert-alert {
  @extend .alert-warning;
}
```

In the body of the application I have

```
<html>      
    <head>
      <title>Language Exchange</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
  <body>
            <% if flash[:alert] %>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <p class="flash-error"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
            <% end %>
            <% if flash[:notice] %>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <p class="flash-notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
             <% end %>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a better answer, please let me know. I solved this issue by removing

```
 <% if flash[:alert] %>
     <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="flash-error"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
 <% end %>
 <% if flash[:notice] %>
     <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="flash-notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
 <% end %>
```

and just adding

```
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

Comment: I don't understand how it can possibly fix your problem. I am assuming you also removed the `extend`s ? (having the same issue).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have other scss files in app/assets/stylesheets that don't include
@import "bootstrap"

I had the same problem on old rails 5 project after an update and
changed Rails.application.config.assets.precompile in config/initializers/assets.rb
in order to limit the compilation to application.scss.

Then in application.scss you can @import the other files.

In details

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = %w( application.scss application.js )
```